# How to show the value of the database to combobox?

Tags: php, html, mysql, combobox

How to show the value of the database to combobox? I've tried like this:

http://pastebin.com/gZL4qAPS

```
$result = $koneksi->query(
    "SELECT tb_sekolah.idSekolah,
        tb_sekolah.namaSekolah,
        tb_sekolah.tb_kategori_sekolah_idKategori,
        tb_kategori_sekolah.namaKategori,
        tb_uptd.namaUPTD,
        tb_sekolah.alamat,
        tb_sekolah.telp,
        tb_sekolah.kataSandi,
        tb_sekolah.status
    FROM tb_sekolah, tb_kategori_sekolah, tb_uptd
    WHERE tb_sekolah.tb_kategori_sekolah_idKategori = tb_kategori_sekolah.idKategori
    AND tb_uptd.idUPTD = tb_sekolah.tb_UPTD_idUPTD
    AND idSekolah='$id'"
);

while ($row = $result->fetch_array()){

    <select name="id_kategori" size="1" class="form-control" required>
        <option label="-- Pilih Kategori --" ></option>
        <?php //looping kategori
        $result1 = $koneksi->query("SELECT * FROM tb_kategori_sekolah"); 
            while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_array()){               
                if ($row['tb_kategori_sekolah_idKategori']==$row1['idKategori']){ 
                    $status = 'selected' ;
                } ?>
                <option <?php echo isset($status)?$status:''; ?> value="<?php echo $row1['idKategori'] ?>"><?php echo $row1['namaKategori']; ?>
                </option>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
    </select>
<?php
}
?>
```

were selected to always be the last value of tb_kategori_sekolah

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.

Answer (score 0):

it is simply because you have not set declare

`$status = NULL;`

inside the While function

your code suppose to be like this

```
<select name="id_kategori" size="1" class="form-control" required>
    <option label="-- Pilih Kategori --" ></option>
    <?php //looping kategori
    $result1 = $koneksi->query("SELECT * FROM tb_kategori_sekolah"); 
        while ($row1 = $result1->fetch_array()){               
            // DECLARE THIS AS NULL
            $status = NULL; 

            if ($row['tb_kategori_sekolah_idKategori']==$row1['idKategori']){ 
                $status = 'selected' ;
            } ?>
            <option <?php echo isset($status)?$status:''; ?> value="<?php echo $row1['idKategori'] ?>"><?php echo $row1['namaKategori']; ?>
            </option>
        <?php
        }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: has been tried and did not succeed

the value of fixed combobox displaying all results from tb_kategori_sekolah

and the variable $status does not work